# MySQL won't start because of AppArmor?

Tags: 16.04, mysql, apparmor

I'm trying to install mysql-server-5.7 on Kubuntu 16.04, but I'm having trouble.

`sudo apt install mysql-server` gives the following output.

```
Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since ons 2017-05-17 09:48:39 CEST; 10ms ago
  Process: 13622 ExecStartPost=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 13621 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=2)
  Process: 13612 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 13621 (code=exited, status=2)

maj 17 09:48:39 anis systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
maj 17 09:48:39 anis systemd[1]: mysql.service: Unit entered failed state.
maj 17 09:48:39 anis systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

And when trying to troubleshoot by running `journalctl -xe` I get output like the following, which seems to indicate that AppArmor is giving me trouble.

```
maj 17 09:53:14 anis systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has begun starting up.
maj 17 09:53:14 anis audit[14767]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/14767/status" pid=14767 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=124 ouid=124
maj 17 09:53:14 anis audit[14767]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/node/" pid=14767 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=124 ouid=0
maj 17 09:53:14 anis kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1495007594.314:240): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/14767/status" pid=14767 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=124 ouid=124
maj 17 09:53:14 anis kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1495007594.314:241): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/node/" pid=14767 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=124 ouid=0
maj 17 09:53:14 anis kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1495007594.314:242): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/14767/status" pid=14767 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=124 ouid=124
maj 17 09:53:14 anis audit[14767]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/14767/status" pid=14767 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=124 ouid=124
maj 17 09:53:14 anis audit[14767]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/14767/task/14767/mem" pid=14767 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=124 ouid=124
maj 17 09:53:14 anis kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1495007594.658:243): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/14767/task/14767/mem" pid=14767 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=124 ouid=124
maj 17 09:53:14 anis systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
```

How could I go about solving this issue?

Comment: Note to future readers: the apparmor denied messages are just warnings, and MySQL is likely exiting for a different reason - see`/var/log/mysql/error.log`. MySQL should still be able to run even if it cannot access the above /proc and /sys files.

Comment: Make sure your disk isn't full.

Comment: For me, the error was due to an incorrect symlink for `/var/lib/mysql`. Reading `/var/log/myql/error.log` allowed me to find the real issue. @SystemParadox

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You need to edit your apparmor configuration to let MySQL access those files. The log messages are telling you that `/usr/sbin/mysqld` needs read (`r`) access to open `/proc/14767/status`, `/sys/devices/system/node/` (trailing slash because it wants to read the directory), and `/proc/14767/task/14767/mem`. The file to edit is `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld`.

In my case I solved the problem by adding these lines somewhere in the middle (with two spaces in front of each):

```
  /proc/*/status r,
  /sys/devices/system/node/ r,
  /sys/devices/system/node/node0/meminfo r,
```

(Note the trailing slash for the second line.)

After doing that, try starting MySQL, and if you get more errors, add those files too and try again.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44573776/mysql-wont-start-anymore/45986591#45986591) is an answer I gave to this problem elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I previously had lines like `/proc/** r,    /sys/devices/system/node/** r, ` in `/etc/apparmour.d/usr.sbin.mysqld` but replacing them with `/proc/*/status r,` and `/proc/*/taks/*/mem r,` seems to have removed the apparmor error messages. MySQL still won't start though, but now just with a single error message shown from journalctl: `sep 09 22:50:47 anis systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT`

Comment: But then I suppose that this question is solved, and my problem is actually something else. I'll try posting a new question for that.

Comment: Why would one need to edit the `apparmour` settings manually to install `mysql`, if that is the case then there's a problem.

Comment: I agree @George ! Here is a launchpad report with others sharing the same issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-5.7/+bug/1610765 (Most commenters report the same log messages as here, although the original reporter had different ones.)

Comment: I followed this answer but I could not start MySQL, it throws the error `mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE`. However, when I rebooted the server, and then removed those 3 lines in the file `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld`, then I could start MySQL.

Comment: `/proc/*/status r` is unnecessarily open. Apparmor has matchers for the current prid, so you can do it like this:

`@{PROC}/@{pid}/status r,`

You might also want to wildcard access to `node*/meminfo` if you have NUMA support / more than one CPU exposed to the machine.

Comment: Also might need to restart apparmor after that:  `sudo service apparmor restart`

Comment: it might make sense to put it into `/etc/apparmor.d/local/user.sbin/mysqld` instead to avoid clashing with default profile updates. It is already included in the default profile

Comment: Looks like no changes are necessary in `apparmor` policies. Looks like it's an `apparmor` cache problem. Try stopping `mysql`, `systemctl restart apparmor.service` and then starting `mysql` again

Answer (score 6):

It may be this:
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=739846
so try using

```
echo "exit 0" >> /etc/init.d/mysql
dpkg --configure -a
```

if it's not helping use:

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common mysql-server-5.5
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

to completly remove your mysql and reinstall
Warning: If you have any databases they will be removed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! My /etc/init.d/mysql already has `exit 0` at the end. I have tried purging and reinstalling mysql-server, which didn't help. I just tried reinstalling (without purging) mysql-common, which also didn't help. Purging it will require me to uninstall a lot of packages that depend on it, which I am a bit scared of.

Comment: I just did do `sudo apt remove --purge mysql-*` to completely remove all MySQL things (I have version 5.7), and then did `sudo apt install akonadi-server mysql-client mysql-server`, but the result is still the same. I still get the same error message and `journalctl -xe` indicates an AppArmor issue as above.

Answer (score 5):

I solved this issue with this:

Edit `/etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.mysqld`

Add the following lines:

```
/data/ r,
/data/** rwk,
```

reload apparmor service

```
sudo service apparmor reload
```

Answer (score 2):

1. `stop mysql-server`
2. `rm /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile*`
3. `restart mysql`

Comment: Please use code markup  `{}` for code,  it makes it more readable. You can edit your answer.

Comment: I renamed my `ib_logfile*` files and did `apt upgrade` but when apt got to mysql, I got the following output
   `mysql_upgrade: [ERROR] 1812: Tablespace is missing for table mysql.plugin`

Comment: great, I tried to tarball it first, mysql removed the tarball, now it is failing to start for a different reason. Ubuntu 18.04. YMMV

Comment: not all fails to start are the same. Deleting ib_logfile* is a sure way to loose data. Its a bad answer, particularly as it doesn't describe how its related to the question.

Answer (score 0):

In my case trying to install mysql-server-5.7 on Ubuntu 16.04
after using the above answers the on thing that worked was:

1. Run `sudo apt install mysql-server`
2. Inspect the above exact error
3. Reboot
4. Run `sudo apt install mysql-server` again to continue installation

Installation completed.

Comment: OK, but that still doesn't work for me, unfortunately.